# I want be able to get products by category, by category AND model or just get all products. Currently using 3 different endpoints for that

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have 3 endpoints on my back-end that return products based on some criteria. I am wondering if I should rewrite the logic and merge it into a single endpoint/function. Currently my routes look like this:

```
router.get('/products', productController.getProducts);
router.get('/products/:categoryId', productController.getProductsByCategory);
router.get('/products/:model/:categoryId', productController.getProductsByModelCategory);
```

And I have 3 functions that are quite similar but also slightly different from each other. I am wondering if I should DRY the code by rewriting one of the functions and removing the other 2 completely. This will make the function more complex with some conditional statements, but I'll remove a lot of duplicate code. On the other hand, with 3 endpoints, it's clear what each one does.

```
module.exports.getProducts = async (req, res, next) => {
    let page = parseInt(req.query.page, 10)
    let limit = 10
    let offset = ( page - 1 ) * limit

    try {
        let products = await Product.findAndCountAll({
            limit: limit,
            offset: offset,
            order: [
                ['createdAt', 'DESC']
            ],
            include: [
                {
                    model: Model
                },
                {
                    model: Brand
                }
            ]
        })

        let pages = Math.ceil( products.count / limit )

        res.status(200).json({
            totalItems: products.count,
            totalPages: pages,
            products: products.rows
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(500)
    }
}

module.exports.getProductsByCategory = async (req, res, next) => {
    let categoryId = req.params.categoryId
    let page = parseInt(req.query.page, 10)
    let limit = 10
    let offset = ( page - 1 ) * limit

    try {
        let products = await Product.findAndCountAll({
            limit: limit,
            offset: offset,
            where: {
                categoryId: categoryId
            }
        })

        let pages = Math.ceil( products.count / limit )

        res.status(200).json({
            totalItems: products.count,
            totalPages: pages,
            products: products.rows
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(500)
    }
}

module.exports.getProductsByModelCategory = async (req, res, next) => {
    let model = req.params.model
    let categoryId = req.params.categoryId
    let page = parseInt(req.query.page, 10)
    let limit = 10
    let offset = ( page - 1 ) * limit

    try {
        let products = await Product.findAndCountAll({
            limit: limit,
            offset: offset,
            where: {
                categoryId: categoryId
            },
            include: {
                model: Model,
                where: {
                    name: model
                }
            }
        })

        let pages = Math.ceil( products.count / limit )

        res.status(200).json({
            totalItems: products.count,
            totalPages: pages,
            products: products.rows
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        res.status(500)
    }
}
```

Comment: Seeing as you don't have an actual problem, you might be better off posting your question on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com). It's a great community with people willing to give feedback about your code.

Answer (score 1):

I would have 3 options if I would be in your place:

1. **Filter in Fronted**

   Get all the data from backend. And then filter it in the frontend.

   That way you wont need 3 separate routes; just one route would do.
2. **Using Params**

   Pass the queries as params in the route followed by `?` .
   You can access params in the controller and use `switch` case or anything similar to show result on the basis of the params. Hence, only one route.
3. One you used.